# Remove items at given positions from a list

Tags: python, list, indexing

I am having difficulty finding a solution to my problem. I need to remove [4,1] from [4,4,4,1,1] and [5,2] from [5,5,2,2,1], only at their first occurrence. The desired result should be [4,4,1] and [5,2,1]. I appreciate your help. Thank you.

Comment: What result do you want if you have [1,2,1,3] and want to remove [1,3]?

Comment: Is this to remove a sequence of _[4, 1]_ from the list, or just the first occurrence of _4_, and first occurrence of _1_?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I made a function which is much simpler. This is similar to competitive programming. So from your question, it looks like, the default is the first number, then when a new number comes, it removes it and the previous number before it.
code:

```
#arr is array
def convert(arr):
    default =arr[0]
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        if arr[i] != default:
            arr.pop(i)
            arr.pop(i-1)
            break
    print(arr)
#put your list inside the function
#convert()
#example
convert([4,4,4,1,1])
convert([5,5,5,2,2])
```

Comment: Why am I down voted... It simple and it works for all test cases

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`list.remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) method.

```py
values = [4, 4, 4, 1, 1]
for value in [4, 1]:
    values.remove(value)
```

Output

```
[4, 4, 1]
```

Comment: I don't think this is what the questioner wanted. This program removes elements this way: If I have a list [4, 4, 2, 1] and want to remove [4, 1] from it, your program gives [4, 2]. I think the questioner expected the elements to be removed in a row?..

Comment: @Beholder, you're saying, only remove the values if they are in a sequence.  Interesting, as this condition is not specified in their question.  I'll leave a comment.

Comment: Hi, thanks for all the answers. list.remove([x,y]) will extract all items named x and y. My goal is to remove only one of each, whatever the index.

Answer (score 0):

Simple but effective:

```
a = [4, 4, 4, 1, 1]
b = [5, 5, 2, 2, 1]

def Remove_part(l, part):
    len_l, len_part = len(l), len(part)
    if len_l < len_part: print("cannot"); return 0 # Checking if it's possible.

    try: # Using try/except because I don't want to care about ids.
        cur_part = l[:len_part] # The part we're comparing to the part to be removed.
        cur_id = 0 # ID of the start of the current part we compare.
        while True:
            if cur_part == part: # Checking if it is the part we looked for.
                return l[:cur_id]+l[cur_id+len_part:] # It won't look for another part.
            # Refresh our part.
            cur_part.pop(0)
            cur_part.append(l[cur_id+len_part])
            cur_id+=1
    except: # This happens if "IndexOutOfRangeException".
        print("not found"); return 0

print(Remove_part(a, [4, 1]))
print(Remove_part(b, [5, 2]))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import pandas as pd
x = pd.Series([4,4,4,1,1])
result = x[x.duplicated(keep='first')].tolist()
```

Comment: Importing and creating a Pandas series for this is waaaaay too overkill. There are much simpler ways.